# Which machine learning algorithms can do multi-categories classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

as a ML Newbie, I'm interested in which machine learning algorithms can do multi-categories classification? Are there different techniques for fewer categories (3) and more categories? And what are the preprocessing required in R or python packages, is it necessary to turn everything into numerical? Thanks.

Comment: Look into using multi-layer perceptrons for classification problems.

Answer (score 2):

Most classification methods can handle multiple classes, for those that can't you can use the one-against-rest method to adapt them.

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) is some documentation on how to do this in python.